# jQuery Start/Stop sequence only works once

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I've written a jQuery sequence for `.ajaxStart` and `.ajaxStop`.  It works exactly how I want it too *(after much trial and error)* but now it only works once, and will not work again without reloading the page.

I thought it was a pretty simple and straight forward sequence, but was I ever wrong. I don't even know what to try at this point I'm already struggling to understand what the problem is.

I've tried with and without a queue, text instead of html, adding the callback to slideUp instead of queue, id's instead of classes. Tried not emptying the post-message. And still.. same thing every time, it just won't work if I submit the same thing twice. I have to refresh the page to get it to work again.

It needs to fire off in a very specific order because I only want one "thing" showing at a time, either the form, loader, or message.

I'm really hoping someone can find what I've done wrong or can point me in the right direction. It would be much appreciated!

## jQuery/AJAX

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $(".post-form").slideUp(250, function(){
        $(".post-loader").fadeIn(250);
    });
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    $(".post-loader").finish().fadeOut(250, function(){
        $(".post-message").slideDown(250).delay(5000).slideUp(250).queue(function(){
            $(this).empty();
            $(".post-form").slideDown(250);
        });
    });
});

$("#add_newblog").click(function(){
    $.post("users/add_blog.php",
    {
    blogtitle:   $("#add_blogtitle").val(),
    blogdate:    $("#add_blogdate").val(),
    blogcontent: $("#add_blogcontent").val()
    },
    function(data){
        $(".post-message").text(data);
    });
});
```

## HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="user-blog-add">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">New Post</h4>
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- SERVER LOADING -->
                <div class="alert alert-primary mt-2 post-loader" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <div class="spinner-grow" role="status">
                            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-primary mt-2 text-center post-message" style="display:none;">
                <!-- SERVER RESPONSE -->
                </div>
                <!-- SERVER AJAX FORM -->
                <div class="post-form" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="add_blogtitle">Post Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add_blogtitle" name="add_blogtitle" maxlength="255" placeholder="My blog title...">
                        <small class="form-text text-muted">Must be less than 255 characters, and contain only letters and/or numbers.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="add_blogdate">Post Date</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add_blogdate" name="add_blogdate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
                        <small class="form-text text-muted">Select a date, or insert your own date in a YYYY-MM-DD format.</small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="add_blogcontent">Post Content</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="add_blogcontent" name="add_blogcontent" rows="4" placeholder="My new blog post..."></textarea>
                        <small class="form-text text-muted">Basic HTML entities are aloud with no attributes, up to and including: Paragraphs, Lists, Italics, and Bold.</small>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block w-50 mx-auto" id="add_newblog">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It appears to me that the animation stops part way through `.ajaxStop` on the second submission. The post-loader fades out, but then the message does not appear and form does not slide back out.

My PHP is not throwing any errors, that still definitely works on the second submission, just the jQuery sequence fails second time through.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the `queue` call. It can be fixed by moving the callback to the `slideUp` method:

```
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $(".post-loader").fadeIn(250);
        $(".post-form").slideUp(250);
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $(".post-loader").finish().delay(2000).fadeOut(250, function () {
            $(".post-message").slideDown(250).slideUp(250, function () {
                $(this).empty();
                $(".post-form").slideDown(250);
            });
        });
    });

    $("#add_newblog").click(function () {
        $.post("test",
            {
                blogtitle: $("#add_blogtitle").val(),
                blogdate: $("#add_blogdate").val(),
                blogcontent: $("#add_blogcontent").val()
            },
            function (data) {
                $(".post-message").text(data);
            });
    });
```

changed part:

**old:**

```
  $(".post-message").slideDown(250).delay(5000).slideUp(250).queue(function(){
            $(this).empty();
            $(".post-form").slideDown(250);
        });
```

**new:**

```
   $(".post-message").slideDown(250).delay(5000).slideUp(250, function(){
                $(this).empty();
                $(".post-form").slideDown(250);
            });
```